# Hypothesis testing with two means: How to do it properly?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have a dataset which looks like the following:

| Value A | Value B |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 100 |
| 1.3 | 200 |
| 1.4 | 300 |
| 1.1 | 433 |
| 1.3 | 320 |
| 1.2 | 210 |
| 1.5 | 108 |

I want to test the following hypothesis:
*If I take an n-dimensional sample, and I rank the elements of the sample according to "Value B", the average of "Value A" in the top half of the ranking is higher than that in the bottom half.

For example, I get a sample of size 4:

| Value A | Value B | Rank (according to Value B) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.6 | 100 | 1 |
| 1.7 | 200 | 2 |
| 1.4 | 300 | 3 |
| 1.3 | 400 | 4 |

In this sample we see that the top 2 positions have a better average than the bottom 2. I would like to verify this hypothesis more strictly using p-values.

**What would be a proper setting of the experiment?**

Comment: That should be doable via a permutation test, permuting the connection between A an B. However I wonder, if a simple correlation test between A and B does not do the trick as well.

Comment: What exactly is the upper and what the lower half when there are 7 rows?

Comment: @Bernhard thanks. Upper and lower half is weakly defined and not strictly binding. If there were 7 rows it could be the top 3 vs the bottom 4 or viceversa.